# How to query data as zabbix system information widget by mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, zabbix

I am writing an API to return System information data. I am using get_status() it return null data when the dashboard have the data as below.

System information

Parameter   Value   Details
Zabbix server is running    Yes 127.0.0.1:10051
Number of hosts (enabled/disabled/templates)    109 16 / 5 / 88
Number of items (enabled/disabled/not supported)    621 328 / 287 / 6
Number of triggers (enabled/disabled [problem/ok])  333 197 / 136 [36 / 161]
Number of users (online)    17  1
Required server performance, new values per second  37.11

I using SQL query to select data from database. But the data for number of items, number of triggers, number of users and server performance doesn't math with the dashboard.  My code as below:
// Items

```
select count(itemid) as numberOfItems from items; => 2630
select count(itemid) as numberOfItems from items JOIN hosts on hosts.hostid = items.hostid  where hosts.`status`=0; => 427
select count(itemid) as numberOfItemEnabled from items JOIN hosts on hosts.hostid = items.hostid where items.STATUS = 0 AND hosts.`status`=0; => 427
select count(itemid) as numberOfItemDisabled from items  JOIN hosts on hosts.hostid = items.hostid  where items.STATUS = 1 AND hosts.`status`=0; => 0
select count(itemid) as numberOfItemNotSupported from items  JOIN hosts on hosts.hostid = items.hostid  where items.state = 1 AND hosts.`status`=0; => 6
```

My reslult:
Number of items (enabled/disabled/not supported)    427 427/ 0/ 6

Web Dashboard: 
Number of items (enabled/disabled/not supported)    621 328 / 287 / 6

// Trigger

```
select count(triggerid) as numberOfTrigger from triggers; => 1329
select count(triggerid) as numberOfTriggerEnabled from triggers where status = 0; => 1328
select count(triggerid) as numberOfTriggerDisabled from triggers where status = 1; => 1
select count(triggerid) as numberOfTriggerOn from triggers where value = 0; => 1273
select count(triggerid) as numberOfTriggerOff from triggers where value = 1; => 56
```

My reslult:
Number of triggers (enabled/disabled [problem/ok])  1329    1328/ 1[1273/ 56
]

Web Dashboard: 
Number of triggers (enabled/disabled [problem/ok])  333 197 / 136 [36 / 161]

```
// Number user online
//Number of users (online)
$numberOfUser = DBfetch(DBselect('select count(userid) as numberOfUser from users'));
$numberOfUserSessions = DBfetchArray(DBselect('select distinct(userid) from sessions'));
$numberOfUserOnline = 0;
foreach ($numberOfUserSessions as $userSession)
{
   $sessionStatus = DBfetchArray(DBselect('select * from sessions where userid = '.$userSession['userid'].' order by lastaccess desc limit 2'));
   if($sessionStatus[0]['status'] !== $sessionStatus[1]['status'])
   {
      $numberOfUserOnline = $numberOfUserOnline + 1;
   }
}
```

My reslult:
Number of users (online)    17  2

Web Dashboard: 
Number of users (online)    17  1

```
// Server performance
$vps_total = DBfetch(DBselect(
    'SELECT sum(vps) AS vps 
             FROM (
             SELECT count(*),count(*)/i.delay as vps
               FROM items i
               JOIN hosts h ON i.hostid=h.hostid 
                 WHERE i.status=0
                   AND h.status=0
                   AND i.type=0
                 GROUP BY i.type,i.delay
                 ORDER BY i.type, i.delay
             ) as data'
      ));

      $server_performance = round($vps_total['vps'], 2);
```

My reslult:
Required server performance, new values per second  35.11

Web Dashboard: 
Required server performance, new values per second  37.11

Please suggest help me the right SQL query for the result same as the web dashboard.

Thank & best regards,
​​​​​​​BienHV

Answer (score 1):

Two ways can get this result:

**1: you can get all info by this url:**

```
http://{zabbix server ip}/zabbix/zabbix.php?action=widget.systeminfo.view
```

you can get the zabbix system info:

```
{
    "header": "System information",
    "body": "<table class="list-table" id="t5e73161796549893369398"><thead><tr><th>Parameter</th><th>Value</th><th>Details</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><th>Zabbix server is running</th><td><span class="green">Yes</span></td><td>localhost:10051</td></tr><tr><th>Number of hosts (enabled/disabled/templates)</th><td>173</td><td><span class="green">1</span> / <span class="red">1</span> / <span class="grey">171</span></td></tr><tr><th><span title="Only items assigned to enabled hosts are counted">Number of items (enabled/disabled/not supported)</span></th><td>285</td><td><span class="green">255</span> / <span class="red">0</span> / <span class="grey">30</span></td></tr><tr><th><span title="Only triggers assigned to enabled hosts and depending on enabled items are counted">Number of triggers (enabled/disabled [problem/ok])</span></th><td>54</td><td>53 / 1 [<span class="red">1</span> / <span class="green">52</span>]</td></tr><tr><th>Number of users (online)</th><td>2</td><td><span class="green">2</span></td></tr><tr><th>Required server performance, new values per second</th><td>2.1</td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>"
}
```

then you can parse this info to get the deatil system info is same as the zabbix dashboard.

**2.by sql query:**

1. hosts info:

```
select status, count(status) hostNumber from hosts where flags = 0 group by status`
```

2. items ifno(Only items assigned to enabled hosts are counted)

```
    select state, count(state) from items  where  hostid in 
        (select hostid from hosts where flags = 0 and status = 0)
     and status = 0 and trends!= 0  group by state
```

3. triggers info (Only triggers assigned to enabled hosts and depending
   on enabled items are counted)

```
        SELECT DISTINCT t.triggerid 
        FROM triggers t,functions f,items i 
        WHERE i.hostid in (select hostid from hosts where flags = 0 and status = 0) 
        AND f.triggerid=t.triggerid 
        AND f.itemid=i.itemid 
        AND t.flags IN (0,4) 
    )
    GROUP BY status
```

4. problems

```
select count(1) from problem where object = 0 and source = 0`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but might be interesting to add to your query list. To get the users currently online you may use this query:

```
SELECT 
t2.userid, 
t2.alias, 
t2.name, 
t2.surname, 
t2.refresh, 
CASE
    WHEN t2.type = 1 THEN 'User'
    WHEN t2.type = 2 THEN 'Admin'
    WHEN t2.type = 3 THEN 'SuperAdmin'
    ELSE t2.type
END AS UserType,
t2.theme, 
t2.attempt_failed, 
t2.attempt_ip, 
t2.attempt_clock, 
t2.rows_per_page,
FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.lastaccess) as lastaccess,
t1.status
FROM sessions as t1
LEFT JOIN users as t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE
    t1.lastaccess IS NOT NULL 
    AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.lastaccess))=CURDATE() 
    AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.lastaccess), NOW())) <= 5
GROUP BY t1.userid, t1.sessionid  
ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.lastaccess) DESC;
```

And if you would like to have them in one line comma separated, use this query:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(FullName SEPARATOR ', ') AS FullName 
FROM
( 
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            t2.name, 
            " ", 
            t2.surname, 
            " (",
            CASE
                WHEN t2.type = 1 THEN 'User'
                WHEN t2.type = 2 THEN 'Admin'
                WHEN t2.type = 3 THEN 'SuperAdmin'
                ELSE t2.type
            END,
            ")"
        ) AS FullName 
    FROM sessions as t1
    LEFT JOIN users as t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
    WHERE
        t1.lastaccess IS NOT NULL  
        AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.lastaccess))=CURDATE() 
        AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.lastaccess), NOW())) <= 5
    GROUP BY t1.userid, t1.sessionid  
    ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.lastaccess) DESC
) t;
```